# How to put PHP variable in array

Tags: php

```
 $booked_seat=array(1,2); 
    if(in_array($seat,$booked_seat)){
                 $booked="red"; $book_seat="data-book='1'"; 
               } else { 
              $booked=""; $book_seat="";
            }
```

I want to put PHP variable in array

```
    $booked_seat=array($id);
```

Is this possible in any way define variable in array?

Comment: what do want at last?? array or string with comma separated??

Comment: can't understand your question mate . give us a valid question with example .

Comment: Unclear question. Be more specific

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. Please make clear what your input, your expected output and your desired behaviour is. Add some examples of input and output. As it stands your question is totally unclear.

Comment: `implode(",", $array);`?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you mean by write array($id)? ......

Comment: @AbhishekKumar You can edit the question and provide more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a string instead of an array of numbers, you can use the join method http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php.

```
 $str = join(',', array(1, 2, 3));
```

If you are wanting to create an array out of a string like '1,2,3' you could use the explode method http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php.

```
$arr = explode(",", "1,2,3");
```

Answer (score 1):

### You can do like this using [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) & [array_shift()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) in php :

```
 $str = '1,2,3';
 $arr = [explode(",", $str)];

 echo "<pre>";
 print_r(array_shift($arr));
```